# Adding more pair of Poles Vs Adding more armature condutor/winding - DC Generator

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

First of all, is it possible to have a DC generator with 4 poles and a single armature winding?

If so what is the difference in DC output generated between a DC generator that has four poles and single armature winding vs a DC generator that has 2 poles and 2 armature windings (along with two pairs of split rings)?

Based on what I remember (or what I misunderstood) in my elementary physics is that, with a DC generator having 2 poles and 2 armature windings, the output DC will pulsate from zero to maximum more number of times (4 times) than a DC generator having 2 poles and 1 armature winding (pulsate 2 times) for a complete rotation of the rotor.

How does the DC output differ in a DC generator having 4 poles and 1 armature winding?